# How do you use SHA256 to create a token of  key,value pairs and a secret signature?

Tags: perl, encryption, sha

I want to validate some hidden input fields (to make sure they arent changed on submission) with the help of a sha-encoded string of the key value pairs of these hidden fields. I saw examples of this online but I didnt understand how to encode and 
decode the values with a dynamic secret value. Can someone help me understand how to do this in perl?

Also which signature type  (MD5, SHA1, SHA256, etc), has a good balance of performance and security?

**update**

So, how do you decode the string once you get it encoded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you really need is not a plain hash function, but a [message authentication code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) such as [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code).  Since you say you'd like to use SHA-256, you might like HMAC_SHA256, which is available in Perl via the [Digest::SHA](http://perldoc.perl.org/Digest/SHA.html#SYNOPSIS-%28HMAC-SHA%29) module:

```
use Digest::SHA qw(hmac_sha256_base64);

my $mac = hmac_sha256_base64( $string, $key );
```

Here, `$key` is an arbitrary key, which you should keep secret, and `$string` contains the data you want to sign.  To apply this to a more complex data structure (such as a hash of key–value pairs), you first need to convert it to a string.  There are several ways to do that; for example, you could use [Storable](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html):

```
use Storable qw(freeze);

sub pairs_to_string {
    local $Storable::canonical = 1;
    my %hash = @_;
    return freeze( \%hash );
}
```

You could also URL-encoding, as [suggested by David Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8830520).  The important thing is that, whatever method you use, it should always return the exact same string when given the same hash as input.

Then, before sending the data to the user, you calculate a MAC for them and include it as an extra field in the data.  When you receive the data back, you remove the MAC field (and save its value), recalculate the MAC for the remaining fields and compare it to the value you received.  If they don't match, someone (or something) has tampered with the data.  Like this:

```
my $key = "secret";
sub mac { hmac_sha256_base64( pairs_to_string(@_), $key ) }

# before sending data to client:
my %data = (foo => "something", bar => "whatever");
$data{mac} = mac( %data );

# after receiving %data back from client:
my $mac = delete $data{mac};
die "MAC mismatch" if $mac ne mac( %data );
```

Note that there are some potential tricks this technique doesn't automatically prevent, such as [replay attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack): once you send the data and MAC to the user, they'll learn the MAC corresponding to the particular set of data, and could potentially replace the fields in a later form with values saved from an earlier form.  To protect yourself against such attacks, you should include enough identifying information in the data protected by the MAC to ensure that you can detect any potentially harmful replays.  Ideally, you'd want to include a unique ID in every form and check that no ID is ever submitted twice, but that may not always be practical.  Failing that, it may be a good idea to include a user ID (so that a malicious user can't trick someone else into submitting their data) and a form ID (so that a user can't copy data from one form to another) and perhaps a timestamp and/or a session ID (so that you can reject old data) in the form (and in the MAC calculation).

Comment: You don't (can't) decode it.  What you do is recalculate it and check that it's the same as what you got back.  I added some sample code to show how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you mean by "unpack", but you can't get original string from the hash.

Let's understand the problem: you render some hidden fields and you want to make sure that they're submitted unchanged, right? Here's how you can ensure that.

Let's suppose you have two variables:

```
first: foo
second: bar
```

You can hash them together with a secret key:

```
secret_key = "ysEJbKTuJU6u"
source_string = secret_key + "first" + "foo" + "second" + "bar"
hash = MD5(source_string)

# => "1adfda97d28af6535ef7e8fcb921d3f0"
```

Now you can render your markup:

```
<input type="hidden" name="first" value="foo" />
<input type="hidden" name="second" value="bar" />
<input type="hidden" name="hash" value="1adfda97d28af6535ef7e8fcb921d3f0">
```

Upon form submission, you get values of `first` and `second` fields, concat them to your secret key in a similar manner and hash again.

If hashes are equal, your values haven't been changed.

Note: **never** render secret key to the client. And sort key/value pairs before hashing (to eliminate dependency on order).

( *disclaimer: I am not a crypto person, so you may just stop reading now*)

As for performance/security, even though MD5 was found to have a weakness, it's still pretty usable, IMHO. SHA1 has a theoretical weakness, although no successful attack has been made yet. There are no known weaknesses in SHA-256.

Comment: Yes, added that before your comment :-)

Answer (score 2):

For this application, any of the encryption algorithms is fine. You can pack the values any way you want, so long as it's repeatable. One common method is to pack the fields into a string the same way you would encode them into a URL for a GET request (name=value).

To compute the hash, create a text secret that can be whatever you want. It should be at least 12 bytes long though. Compute the hash of the secret concatenated with the packed fields and append that onto the end.

So, say you picked MD5, a secret of `JS90320ERHe2` and you have these fields:

```
first_name = Jack
last_name = Smith
other_field = 7=2
```

First, URL encode it:

```
first_name=Jack&last_name=Smith&other_field=7%3d=2
```

Then compute the MD5 hash of

```
JS90320ERHe2first_name=Jack&last_name=Smith&other_field=7%3d=2
```

Which is `6d0fa69703935efaa183be57f81d38ea`. The final encoded field is:

```
first_name=Jack&last_name=Smith&other_field=7%3d=2&hash=6d0fa69703935efaa183be57f81d38ea
```

So that's what you pass to the user. To validate it, remove the hash from the end, compute the MD5 hash by concatenating what's left with the secret, and if the hashes match, the field hasn't been tampered with.

Nobody can compute their own valid MD5 because they don't know to prefix the string with.

Note that an adversary can re-use any old valid value set. They just can't create their own value set from scratch or modify an existing one and have it test valid. So make sure you include something in the information so you can verify that it is suitable for the purpose it has been used.

Comment: i like the URL parameterization

Comment: You strip the `&hash=...` from the end. Validate the hash, and then URL decode the rest of the string just like you would on a GET request.